How can I import lib-r-math.js in vite app?
I'm trying to use the functions in lib-r-math.js in a vite app.
I have installed lib-r-math.js in the project with:
npm i lib-r-math.js

and I have the following code for demo app:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { qnorm } from 'lib-r-math.js';

const num = ref(.5);

function getR(x){
  return qnorm(x)
}

</script>

<template>

  <main>
    <textarea v-model='num'></textarea>
    <textarea>{{getR(num)}}</textarea>
  </main>
</template>

When I run the demo app with npm run dev, I get the following in my browser console:

Module "crypto" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "crypto.randomBytes" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.

and
Uncaught TypeError: import_crypto.randomBytes is not a function
    seed seed.mjs:3
    MersenneTwister index.mjs:15
    <anonymous> global-rng.mjs:157

I have read the doc suggested but I am no closer to understanding how to include the library. What is the correct way of including lib-r-math.js so that the code functions?
